# Can't add java security exception to my own app

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Java now requires signed apps or for the site/jar to be in the security exception list.

I'm locally testing a website and have the jar & jnlp located in the webroot of the server. I'm unable to start the program via java web start in the browser due to an "Application Blocked by Java Security" error. I'm trying to add the file to the exception list but it won't work.

I've tried (.2 is the virtual host, btw):

```
http://127.0.0.2/launch.jnlp
http://127.0.0.2/app.jar
file://c:/wamp64/project/webroot/app.jar
file://c/wamp64/project/webroot/app.jar
```

If I try to manually start the app via javaws I get the security prompt but the "Location" of the file on the prompt is "file://" I can't add "file://" to the exception list nor do I understand why it thinks there's no path to the jar.

Really not sure what to do... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can add the FILE exception if you add an extra trailing slash:

```
file:///
```